# Toggle Darkmode in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, ejs

i want to make some code with javascript, html and css to toggle darkmode and nightmode. But i dont know how to do it

[image: I Have a button with class btn-night (line 22) to switch from light mode to dark mode]

[image: I want to change "ralue-theme.min.css" in line 14 to ralack-theme.min.css with javascript]

so, when i click the button in line 22, i want it to be able that button to change the stylesheet rel in line 14 from "/dist/css/skins/ralue-theme.min.css" to "/dist/css/skins/ralack-theme. min. css"

*I'm using EJS btw

Answer (score 0):

You should add an onclick event in line 22 and define a function like switchMode in your js file.

You can handle this situation with add and delete classes.

Also please use snippet for codes next time don't send photos like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeAttribute` and `setAttribute` for change the link src. See example:

HTML FILE:

```
<!--Line 14 of HTML-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/skins/ralue-theme.min.css" id="link" />
<!--Here we add a id="link"-->

<!--Line 22 of html-->
<a id="nightMode" class="btn btn-night btn-default btn-block fa fa-moon-o" />
```

JS FILE:

```
let nightButton = document.querySelector("#nightMode");
let styleSheet = document.querySelector("#link");

nightButton.addEventListener("click",() => {
styleSheet.removeAttribute("src")
styleSheet.setAttribute("src","dist/css/skins/ralack-theme. min. css") 
})
```

See [element.setAttribute documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [element.removeAttribute documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)